# Error: Cannot find module when using ng serve --aot

Tags: angular, angular7, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular7-router

I migrated my angular project from 6 to 7, I'm using lazy loading mechanism to load the modules. But when i'm taking the production build or serve the project with aot true `ng serve --aot`
getting the following error.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module
>   'app/modules/home/home.module' Error: Cannot find module
>   'app/modules/home/home.module'

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.2",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-countries": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-mention": "0.0.5",
    "angular-mentions": "^0.9.0",
    "angular-text-input-autocomplete": "^0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase": "^5.5.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.0.2",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "keyboardevent-key-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "ng-dynamic": "^3.0.2",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.13",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.3.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^8.1.4",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.3.9",
    "ngx-img-cropper": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.14.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "nouislider": "^10.1.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

**This is my app.routing.module.ts**

```
              {
                path: 'home',
                loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule'
              },
              {
                path: 'top',
                loadChildren: 'app/modules/top/top.module#TopModule'
              },
              {
                path: 'story/:storyId',
                loadChildren: 'app/modules/story/story.module#StoryModule'
              },
              {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
              }
```

**This is my directory structure**

```
Project
  src
    app
      app.module.ts
      app.routing.module.ts
      modules
        home
          homedir.module.ts
```

Finally this is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

Build works fine with aot false. But I really need a solution to this problem. I've also tried with absolute path and `loadChildren: () => HomeModule`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please make sure your home module name is HomeModule because your filename is homdir.module.ts and accordingly make correction in  app.routing.module.ts for path home.

Comment: Yes i've verified. :(

Answer (score 2):

With the new version of Angular, we prefere to write the import like this:

`loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule) }`

So use a RELATIVE path.